# PHP: Echoing XML code- variable in the tag

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I need to echo XML code: 
`echo '<Say voice= "woman" language="fr">''</Say>';`

But I want the "woman" to be a variable that I could change.

What is the correct formatting to do this?

Comment: `echo '<Say voice= "'.$voice.'" language="fr">stuff</Say>';` Give `$voice` whatever value you want. Also, escape the inner quotes

Comment: Thank you! Put this in an answer if you want me to accept it;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable and use it in the echo like:

```
echo '<Say voice= "'.$voice.'" language="fr">stuff</Say>';
```

Give $voice whatever value you want.

Also, escape the inner quotes if you need any!

```
echo '<Say voice= "'.$gender.'" language="fr">\'\'</Say>';
```